# Change FilePath of CS-Script AsmHelper Object

Tags: c#, cs-script

I am using the [AsmHelper](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script/blob/master/Source/CSScriptLibrary/AsmHelper.cs) class in the [CS-Script](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script) library. I am wondering how to only use one AsmHelper object and just change the filepath using `CSScript.LoadCode` so I can load a new script after the previous script is done, but with only one AsmHelper object. Right now, as shown below, I have four AsmHelper objects.

```
        AsmHelper transform1 = new AsmHelper
            (CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\parent.cs", null, true));
        ITransform engine1 = (ITransform)transform1.CreateObject("Script");

        AsmHelper transform2 = new AsmHelper
            (CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\bYear.cs", null, true));
        ITransform engine2 = (ITransform)transform2.CreateObject("Script");

        AsmHelper transform3 = new AsmHelper
            (CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\fInitial.cs", null, true));
        ITransform engine3 = (ITransform)transform3.CreateObject("Script");

        AsmHelper transform4 = new AsmHelper
            (CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\pet.cs", null, true));
        ITransform engine4 = (ITransform)transform4.CreateObject("Script");
```

Here is the interface that goes with it if needed:

```
public interface ITransform
{
    User Transform(User record);
}
```

If you need me to provide additional details, just ask below.

Answer (score 0):

You should not reuse `AsmHelper`. It was designed early days for a single script use-case. That's why it is IDisposable.

The AsmHelper rsponsibility is accessing script methods via 'Dispatch' invocation model, handling script specific assembly probing and unloading script assembly when it's loaded in  a remote AppDomain.

Since you are not using none of these features you are much better off by using newer APIs:

```
var engine1 = (ITransform)CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\parent.cs", null, true)
                                  .CreateObject("Script");

var engine2 = (ITransform)CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\bYear.cs", null, true)
                                  .CreateObject("Script");

var engine3 = (ITransform)CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\fInitial.cs", null, true)
                                  .CreateObject("Script");

var engine4 = (ITransform)CSScript.LoadCode(@"CS-Scripts\pet.cs", null, true)
                                  .CreateObject("Script");
```

If you install CS-Script NuGet package it will add to your VS project a few sample files that demonstrate these techniques.

Comment: I was previously doing it like that but the reason I am using AsmHelper is so I can unload it and save memory.

Comment: Do you know how to unload the AsmHelper?

Comment: But the code you provided in your original post never unloads. You supposed to use different AsmHelper constructor that actually ensures AppDomain unloading upon disposal. Have a look at the code samples and you will see how it's done.